# Create Link to a remote git repo

Tags: git

I have a remote git repo and its URL.

I want to create a local folder with a link to the HEAD of this repo.

**I don't want to clone the repo to my pc.**

How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Where is this repository located(on github or some hosting site)?

Comment: it is located in a hosting site

Comment: You can't do this with git. The purpose of git is, that you always have the full history. So you have to clone it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am uncertain as to what specific purpose you'd like to achieve here, and whether that purpose isn't readily achievable by easier means.

Nevertheless.

- [Gitfs](https://github.com/PressLabs/gitfs) allows you to mount a git repo's HEAD as local directory, using FUSE.
- [GVFS](https://github.com/Microsoft/GVFS) allows you do the same on Windows. Biggest difference is that GVFS WILL copy all the files you touch in the git repo; which at limits means if you touch all the files, you *will* clone the repo at full.

Working remotely like this might have the advantage of not having to store the sourcecode on your local computer; however, note the disadvantage in terms of drastically increased latency (having to commit per-file), and unreadable version history (having to commit per-file) due to this workflow.

In particular, due to the second reason, you might find it incredibly difficult to work together with other people on any repo -merging your change history will be a PITA.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check GIT's documentation in regards for adding your existing remote to your repo:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: Link only answers are seen as not-high-quality answers. I suggest to put this answer as a comment.

Comment: Noted. Though pretty much I dont have that feature available in my account anyways

Comment: Yes, I know. But if you want to avoid getting downvoted you better wait until you really have the 'feature' available.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the advice